# How do I change color depending on the color of the section that scrolls past

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been asked many times if I could develop a site where the logo changes its color if a section scrolls past that has the same or a similar color. I could not imagine a way to do this.

However I came across this site yesterday that realized that exact effect:

http://www.fcinq.com/

*(Look at the logo on the top right and scroll down until the logo moves over the light background.)*

How would you go about creating that effect?

Can anyone point me in the direction of a snippet or tutorial that explains this effect? I couldn't figure out how that was done.

Comment: http://codepen.io/timaikens/pen/gbPEor hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Inspect it in dev tools. FCINQ does it by using a mask, notice how `#footer-wrapper` has a `.site-logo-mask` containing a duplicated, fixed position logo of another color. `.site-logo-mask` is clipping the content (including the duplicated fixed logo) using `clip: rect(0, auto, auto, 0);`. Clever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give a try using this .

http://aerolab.github.io/midnight.js/

May be helpful  for you .

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! That seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.